# How can I get all NFTs for a wallet without using metaplex-foundation/js

Tags: metaplex, nft, query

Given the public key of a wallet, how would one get all the NFTs owned by this wallet, **without** using the metaplex-foundation/js package?

The reason I don't want to use metaplex's library is because they consider it *experimental* and hence not *suitable* for production.

I would still like to do it in js, with @solana/web3, but not the metaplex wrapper library because it's noted as experimental in the docs. (Yes, I know that everybody uses it anyways, but these are my employers requirements, not mine)

Thanks

Comment: you state what you don't want to use, but not what you do.  shall we provide answers in python? C? COBOL?

Comment: I'd like to do it in js, with `@solana/web3`, but not the metaplex wrapper library because it's noted as experimental in the docs. (I know that everybody uses it anyways, but these are my employers requirements, not mine)

Comment: @trent.sol same here - as https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js notes, metaplex is 0.x, interfaces change between versions, there's no changelog, and Metaplex can sometimes break in odd ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to get all `SPL token accounts` and then parse the accounts where the mint meets the `NFT requirements` for Solana (total supply 1, no mint authority)

You can use Solana JSON RPC to [retrieve all token accounts](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner)

alternatively, you can use `@solana/web3` [Connection](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html)

```
import {Connection, PublicKey} from '@solana/web3'
import { getMint } from "@solana/spl-token";


const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com')
const ownerAddress = new PublicKey('<YourAddress>')

// get token accounts
const token_accounts 
 = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(ownerAddress,{programId:<TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID>})

// parse token accounts one by one
// 1 - get mint using getMint(..)
// 2 - get Token total supply using connection.getTokenSupply(..)
// 3 - get mint authority using connection.getAccountInfo(..)
// 4 - check if the user balance is equal to 1 otherwise it's an empty token account. Use connection.getBalance(..)
// 5 - do mint checks that I specified.
```

This is a low-level implementation. You can refere to [this code](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/137/how-do-i-get-all-nfts-for-a-given-wallet?rq=1) if you want an easier way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I believe the NFT requirements on Solana include the presence of a (Master) Edition account, hence there can be a mint authority that is a PDA. But I should be able to find that by tweaking your solution.