# How do I check if connected wallet has X NFT?

Tags: nft, dapp

I'm using the Solana dApp Scaffold to build a basic app.

How do I check if the connected wallet has X NFT?

Comment: by `X` NFT do you mean if the wallet has a specific NFT from a collection? Or any NFT from a particular collection?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

You can use [solana/web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/). [get all token accounts by owner](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenAccountsByOwner) then check if the [token account with a certain mint has a balance of 1](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenAccountBalance).

**Solution 2**

[Get all NFTs](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/137/how-do-i-get-all-nfts-for-a-given-wallet) then check if there's the NFT you are looking for.

```
import { Metaplex, keypairIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

(async () => {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");
  const keypair = Keypair.generate();

  const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
  metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

  const owner = new PublicKey("2R4bHmSBHkHAskerTHE6GE1Fxbn31kaD5gHqpsPySVd7");
  const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(owner).run();

  console.log(allNFTs);
})();
```