# Find Staked NFTs Of A Wallet

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, staking

I want to build a portfolio tracker for SOL wallets.
I'm stuck on finding the staked NFTs of a user(wallet).
Do I have to dig over the transactions or is there a smart way to find the staked NFTs of a wallet?

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/137/how-do-i-get-all-nfts-for-a-given-wallet

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: Native staking only works with SOL. Could you clarify what NFT staking is? (program ID & link to documentation)